# XSLT: XML node rendering issue

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing

I am trying to render a sample XML using an XSLT as shown below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<root>
<title>test</title>
<description> This is the first description</description>
<description>This is for
      <subject>testing</subject>every day
</description> 
</root>
```

I am using the following XSLT code to display the description nodes.

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="root/description">
<p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
</xsl:for-each>`
```

This is the output that I am getting.

```
This is the first description
    
This is for testing every day
```

Could you please suggest, why it is showing **testing** in the 2nd description node?

**testing** is under the subject node. Because of formatting, I want to get the subject node using `<xsl:value-of select="subject"/>` code.

Could you please suggest what could be the solution?

Thank you very much.

Regards, AK

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67950714/xml-structure-not-getting-rendered-using-xslt?noredirect=1

Comment: Sure, Thank you for pointing it out. It happened by mistake. I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT-1.0, the expression `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` selects the `text()` values of all *descendant* nodes and concatenates them. To select only all direct children, you have to apply another for-each like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="root/description">
  <p>
    <xsl:for-each select="text()">   <!- Select all direct text() children -->
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>    
    </xsl:for-each>
  </p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Then, the output will be the following:

```
<p>This is the first description </p>
<p>This is for every day </p>
```

---

EDIT (with additional requirements):

You can match the `text()` nodes with specific parent elements:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="root/description">
      <p><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" /></p>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
  
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subject/text()">
    <b><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></b>
</xsl:template>
```

Output is:

```
<p>This is the first description </p>
<p>
    This is for <b>testing</b>
every day </p>
```

This approach can add highlighting elements to the output. But I don't know how to get rid of superfluous spaces, so this is (maybe) as good as it gets.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one clarification. If I want to show the description like "This is for testing every day" by breaking the description into "This is for" and "every day" and then insert formatted "testing" in-between the two phrases? How can I do it? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you very much. What does "<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />" code do?

Comment: If possible, could you please share your insights about this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68013032/xslt-throwing-error-due-to-encoded-characters?noredirect=1#comment120231614_68013032

Comment: This is a different question. I answered your question and also a follow-up extension of it. Please mark this answer as "accepted" by clicking the arrow on the left side. This is expected behavior on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working. I really appreciate your support. I can't see the option to accept the answer. Also, I didn't mean to get an answer to another post here but just wanted to share if you're interested to take a look at my other post and could possibly share any insights there on that post. Thank you again for your support and time.

Comment: It is simple: just click on the light-grey arrow on the upper-left corner of my answer. That's all that SO expects of a user. But anyways - glad I could help.

Comment: That arrow didn't seem like one can click it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

`xsl:value-of` can only create strings. If you want the `subject` element included in the output, use `xsl:copy-of` instead of `xsl:value-of`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one clarification. If I want to show the description like "This is for testing every day" by breaking the description into "This is for" and "every day" and then insert formatted "testing" in-between the two phrases? How can I do it? Any suggestion is appreciated.