# XSLT throwing error due to encoded characters

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I am using an external entity reference "ISOEntities" in my XML file for special characters but it is not getting included in the file and XML is giving an error due to encoded special characters.

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>

<!DOCTYPE root[
<!ENTITY % ISOEntities PUBLIC "ISO 8879-1986//ENTITIES ISO Character Entities 20030531//EN//XML" "http://www.s1000d.org/S1000D_4-0-1/ent/ISOEntities">
%ISOEntities;
]>
<root>
<description> This is description &amp;</description>
</root>
```
I am using the following XSLT for display:
```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<html>
<body>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <h1>Description:<xsl:value-of select="root/description" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></h1>
  </xsl:template>

 </body>
</html>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Am I parsing the encoded character node properly?

Could you please suggest what could be the problem with the XSLT code as it is not displaying anything when an encoded special character is there in the XML node?

Thank you very much for your support and time.

Regards,
AK
````

Comment: Study the documentation of your XML parser on how to set it up to read in DTDs, these days they are usually ignored due to security reasons so to use them you have to explicitly change settings.

Comment: What is the **exact** error message you get? Your stylesheet has several errors that have nothing to do with entity references or special characters.

Comment: Thank you. It is not showing any specific message to track the error. It is showing "Failed to apply XSLT to the content. ". Could you please point to the errors in the XSLT or please post the code you think is correct?

Comment: See a corrected XSLT here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/asoTJY

Comment: Thank you very much. I can see your code is working, however, it is still not working in the OOTB XML viewer in SharePoint. Could you please share what encoding you used for the code in XML and XSLT?

Comment: Also, I observe different parsers are giving different errors in fiddle.

Comment: The errors are due to the online nature of the tool. Likewise, the encoding is irrelevant when there is no actual file. -- If the same code does not work for you, then I believe the question is about SharePoint, not XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give details of what XML parser you are using, and how you are invoking it.

The world has become security-obsessed, and many parsers these days switch off external entity expansion by default, even when there is a public ID which should be totally secure. Quite a few parsers ignore DTDs entirely.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your reply. I don't know which parser is used as I am using out of box component (dot net framework) in SharePoint to process and transform XML using XSLT. I tried with an online parser, it was giving me the same error. I think it is problem with XSLT. Maybe I am not displaying it with the right code.  I updated the code for your reference. Any suggestion is appreciated?

Comment: Also, do you think if we can download an external entity file and refer to XML, will it work?

Comment: On .NET you're almost certainly using the Microsoft `System.Xml.XmlReader` parser. This will read external DTDs and entity files if invoked with the right options, but by default it ignores them. If Sharepoint doesn't give you any control over these options, then you're probably hosed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insights. I appreciate it if you could suggest changes in my XSLT code so that I come to conclusion whether it is XML parser restriction or a problem with my code.

Comment: The failure clearly occurs during the XML parsing operation long before your XSLT code comes into the picture: nothing you do to your XSLT code is going to make any difference.